# Find constant $c < 1$, such that Fibonacci number $F(n) \le 2^{cn}$ for every $n \ge 0$

Tags: calculus

I have an outline for solution, but I am afraid that it's not mathematically rigorous at all. Would you be so kind to point problems with this solution if any?

1) I looked up in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) that $F(n)$ tends to $\frac{\varphi^n - (-\frac{1}{\varphi})^n}{\sqrt 5}$ while $n \to \infty$, where $\varphi = \frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2}$

2) Consequently [$F(n) \in \Theta(\varphi^n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)

3) So to find the constant $c$ we need to solve equation $2^{cn} = (\frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2})^n$, which implies $c = \log_2{(1 + \sqrt 5)} - 1$

Comment: This all looks good. To make it mathematically rigorous, observe that $F_n\leq \phi^n/\sqrt{5}<\phi^n.$

Comment: $g(n) \in O(f(n))$ implies $g(n) \le cf(n)$ eventually. This does not mean that $g(n)=f(n)$

Comment: @AlexS $-1/\phi < 0$, so for odd $n$, we have $F_n > \phi^n/\sqrt{5}$. But $F_n \leqslant (\phi^n + 1)/\sqrt{5} \leqslant 2\phi^n/\sqrt{5} < \phi^n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Good call. I missed the minus inside the parentheses.

Comment: @DanielFischer When I correct all the issues commentators pointed out. Do I need to answer my own question or edit body of a question? (don't want to create new question on http://meta.stackexchange.com about it)

Comment: Not so much "correcting issues", more "filling in left out parts". Note that what you have already implies that you must have $c \geqslant \log_2 (1+\sqrt{5}) - 1$, and that every constant greater than that works except possibly for finitely many $n$, so what's missing is the verification/the proof that $\log_2 (1+\sqrt{5}) - 1$ already works. Don't edit an answer in the body of your question. Either post an answer yourself, or convince one (or more) of the commenters to post an answer.

Comment: Why does "Wikipedia" link to youtube?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Because I use Linux and sometimes confuse my "Ctrl+C" buffer with  "mouse wheel button" buffer and vice versa. Corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\phi^2=\phi+1$ so that  $F(n)\le \phi^n$ and $F(n+1)\le \phi^{n+1}$ implies 
$$F(n+2)=F(n+1)+F(n)\le \phi^{n+1}+\phi^n=(\phi+1)\phi^n =\phi^2\phi^n=\phi^{n+2}.$$
As $F(0)\le 1=\phi^0$ and $F(1)\le 1<\phi^1$, we conclude by induction $F(n)\le\phi^n$ for all $n\ge 0$. As you already noted, this allows us to let $c=\log_2\phi$, which is $<1$ (because $\phi<2$). Observe that your finding about the asymptotic behaviour can help *guessing* the exponent, but a proof for *all* nonnegative $n$ needs to have an eye on the all terms, especially the initial terms.