# Finding constant $c < 1$ such that $F_n ≤ 2^{cn}$ for all $n ≥ 0$

Tags: asymptotics, fibonacci-numbers

I am required to find a constant $c < 1$ such that $F_n ≤ 2^{cn}$ for all $n ≥ 0$. I tried to come up with a method to do so, but I'm not quite sure whether it makes a lot of sense. Could someone please help correct this?

We know $ F_{k + 1} = F_k + F_{k - 1}$ and  $F_n ≤ 2^{cn}$

Hence,
$F_{k + 1} \le 2^{ck} + 2^{c(k - 1)} = 2^{ck}(1 + 2^{-c})$

Also, $F_{k + 1} \le 2^{c(k + 1)} = 2^{ck}(1 + 2^c)$

Taking the cases where the above cases are equal to $F_{k + 1}$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
2^{ck}\cdot 2^c &= 2^{ck}(1 + 2^{-c}) \\
2^{2c} &= 2^c + 1 \\
2^{2c} - 2^c - 1 &= 0 \\
2^c &= \phi \\
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ . Hence, $2^{cn} = \phi^n \implies cn\log_2{2} = n\log_2{\phi} \implies \boxed{c = \log_2{\phi}}$

How would I obtain a constraint for all valid $c$? I've read another [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1343898/857163), which seems more correct. Should I instead go by that solution, or is this one fine?

Comment: Hagen's solution at the duplicate is very nice. You are doing a similar thing, so why not compare it with Hagen's solution. Your start is confusing. Are you assuming already $F_n<2^{cn}$? You are supposed to show this!

Comment: oh, it was meant to link to his solution. i did notice the similarity; i was more concerned with whether this is complete/correct and how i would make it complete if not because i wasn't able to strike a direct parallel between our solutions.

Comment: You have to show $2^{ck} + 2^{c(k - 1)} = 2^{ck}(1 + 2^{-c})\le 2^{c(k + 1)} = 2^{ck}(2^c)$. Once you do that, you will get your range of all valid c, this is because now $F_{k+1} \le 2^{ck} + 2^{c(k - 1)} = 2^{ck}(1 + 2^{-c})\le 2^{c(k + 1)} = 2^{ck}(2^c)$

Comment: @DietrichBurde i thought i just needed to find the constant, why would i need to prove that? should i use the constant obtained to then prove that $F_n≤2^{cn}$ using induction or such?

Comment: Yes, it is a priori not clear in your title, that we *can* estimate $F_n$ by $2^{cn}$ with a  positive contstant $c<1$ at all. You have to show this - and Hagen did nicely already.